samba-tool --use-kerberos=required fails to authenticate
I am struggling for days trying to further in my samba active directory quest. Learned a lot, but am I quite stuck now.
The thing I am trying to achieve, is to get isc-dhcp updating samba's internal DNS (in short, get ddns working). After some trouble and adding some log statements in their (samba's) dhcp-dyndns.sh script, I came closer to the root cause, and eventually found a way to reproduce the problem.
In short what goes on in the dhcp-dyndns.sh script as far as I understand:

it assumes a user is added in samba 'dhcpduser' which should be the user that add/removes records to the DNS database
it assumes there is a 'keytab' file stored on disk in /etc/dhcpduser.key
every time isc-dhcp "commits" a new computer, it calls the dhcp-dyndns script
the script will internally then check if it still has a valid kerberos ticket, if not, it will be created
next it will use the samba tool to add/delete records in samba's internal database.

The last step, fails.
An example of one of the exact calls orchestrated by the dhcp-dyndns script:
samba-tool dns add server spatiebas.net hp-ubuntu A 192.168.2.163 --use-kerberos=required

where:

server is the name of my ubuntu (24.04) server
spatiebas.net is my domain name
hp-ubuntu is one of the computers in my lan
192.168.2.163 is the IP address dealt out by isc-dhcp

When I call the exact same command from my laptop, or on the server directly logged in over ssh:
bas@spatiebas.net@hp-ubuntu:~$ sudo samba-tool dns add server spatiebas.net hp-ubuntu A 192.168.2.163 --use-kerberos=required
Failed to bind to uuid 50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076 for ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.2.100[49153,sign,target_hostname=server,abstract_syntax=50abc2a4-574d-40b3-9d66-ee4fd5fba076/0x00000005,localaddress=192.168.2.163] NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
ERROR: Connecting to DNS RPC server server failed with (3221225473, '{Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful.')

The error message doesn't really point me in any direction, as it's a bit "general". Also googling the error message, or some parts, gives plenty of hits, but nothing to gets me further.
What I DID find out, is that the command SUCCEEDS when I leave out the --use=kerberos=required. So without the use-kerberos it finds another way of authenticating with the active directory server.
Unfortunately for me, leaving out the --use-kerberos=required part in the dhcp-dyndns script, does not work. I lack knowledge on many things to understand why.
So, my challenge, I think, is figuring out why the command refuses to succeed when I add the --use-kerberos part.
I also ran tcpdump on the server capturing port 88 in the hope it would reveal a hint. It's not much, but at least I can see communication going back and forth until the server replies "error-code: eRR-PREAUTH-REQUIRED (25)".
Attaching a screenshot for what it's worth:

Again, googling that error did not get me much further.
Is there anyone that can tell me more about this problem?

which part in samba should I investigate?
are there specific parts in smb.conf that I should add to get "kerberos RPC" going?
what is causing the problem? client side? server side? what can I check client side? what can I check server side?

Any information that helps me further is much appreciated!
For completeness:
smb config:
# Global parameters
[global]
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8 9.9.9.9
        netbios name = SERVER
        realm = SPATIEBAS.NET
        server role = active directory domain controller
        workgroup = SPATIEBAS
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

        # disable IPv6 according to chat gpt
#       smb ports = 445
        interfaces = 192.168.2.100
#       bind interfaces only = yes

        allow dcerpc auth level connect = yes
        allow dns updates = nonsecure

        kerberos method = system keytab

        log level = 3

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/spatiebas.net/scripts
        read only = No


Kerberos config
[libdefaults]
        udp_preference_limit = 0
        default_realm = SPATIEBAS.NET
        rdns = false
        dns_lookup_realm = true
        dns_lookup_kdc = true



That "disable ipv6" part seems silly... Which Samba version, though? When they first added the 'new' --use-kerberos= option (as opposed to the old -k option like smbclient has), if I remember correctly, it worked a bit differently and required a ticket cache to be manually specified – whereas if you didn't use the option, it'd get tickets from your "default" ticket cache (the one klist shows).

Hi @u1686_grawity, yes I will remove the gpt provided ipv6 suggestion, don't think I need it either. I am using 4.19, from latest ubuntu repos installed a couple of weeks ago

I don't exactly know what restrictions are added that this script needs to execute as the dhcpd user. I guess that's why it needs the --use-kerberos argument. I can ofc try the -k, which is deprecated in samba-tool but still there I noticed. No clue if it will make a difference though (or if it works at all).

Does --use-kerberos=required --use-krb5-ccache="$KRB5CCNAME" make it work?

No, but thanks for the tip. Googled a bit what it means, and it was a good suggestion. Do you know what kind of kerberos I am using? I read somewhere that some "heimdal" kerberos server is running inside samba ad by default. That it can be replaced with another one. I just installed samba through apt, so I did nothing special for kerberos. I would like to have some checks that would reveal something that is missing / misconfigured. It feels a whole lot "blackbox" now, with nothing to go on.

Samba AD can be configured to use either MIT Krb5 or Heimdal (both traditional Unix Kerberos implementations), but for most purposes they both function almost exactly the same way (Samba adapts both to be equally AD-like). In the latter case it can be built against system Heimdal or against its own bundled copy of Heimdal. The client-side implementation probably matters slightly more, either way.
